# Intercepting logger.info from other class' method

Tags: python, logging

I would like to intercept all logger.info logs from other class' method. Here is my code:

```
from mega.mega import Mega

mega = Mega()
m = mega.login(email, password)
m.upload('sample_file.txt')
```

In mega.mega.py file there is import from logging

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

In this moment while uploading a file, I would like to print all logs for example:

- logger.info('Chunks uploaded')
- logger.info('Setting attributes to complete upload')
- logger.info('Computing attributes')

Here is upload method from Mega class:

```
    def upload(self, filename, dest=None, dest_filename=None):
        # determine storage node
        if dest is None:
            # if none set, upload to cloud drive node
            if not hasattr(self, 'root_id'):
                self.get_files()
            dest = self.root_id

        # request upload url, call 'u' method
        with open(filename, 'rb') as input_file:
            file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
            ul_url = self._api_request({'a': 'u', 's': file_size})['p']

            # generate random aes key (128) for file
            ul_key = [random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFFFF) for _ in range(6)]
            k_str = a32_to_str(ul_key[:4])
            count = Counter.new(
                128, initial_value=((ul_key[4] << 32) + ul_key[5]) << 64)
            aes = AES.new(k_str, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=count)

            upload_progress = 0
            completion_file_handle = None

            mac_str = '\0' * 16
            mac_encryptor = AES.new(k_str, AES.MODE_CBC,
                                    mac_str.encode("utf8"))
            iv_str = a32_to_str([ul_key[4], ul_key[5], ul_key[4], ul_key[5]])
            if file_size > 0:
                for chunk_start, chunk_size in get_chunks(file_size):
                    chunk = input_file.read(chunk_size)
                    upload_progress += len(chunk)

                    encryptor = AES.new(k_str, AES.MODE_CBC, iv_str)
                    for i in range(0, len(chunk) - 16, 16):
                        block = chunk[i:i + 16]
                        encryptor.encrypt(block)

                    # fix for files under 16 bytes failing
                    if file_size > 16:
                        i += 16
                    else:
                        i = 0

                    block = chunk[i:i + 16]
                    if len(block) % 16:
                        block += makebyte('\0' * (16 - len(block) % 16))
                    mac_str = mac_encryptor.encrypt(encryptor.encrypt(block))

                    # encrypt file and upload
                    chunk = aes.encrypt(chunk)
                    output_file = requests.post(ul_url + "/" +
                                                str(chunk_start),
                                                data=chunk,
                                                timeout=self.timeout)
                    completion_file_handle = output_file.text
                    logger.info('%s of %s uploaded', upload_progress,
                                file_size)
            else:
                output_file = requests.post(ul_url + "/0",
                                            data='',
                                            timeout=self.timeout)
                completion_file_handle = output_file.text

            logger.info('Chunks uploaded')
            logger.info('Setting attributes to complete upload')
            logger.info('Computing attributes')
            file_mac = str_to_a32(mac_str)

            # determine meta mac
            meta_mac = (file_mac[0] ^ file_mac[1], file_mac[2] ^ file_mac[3])

            dest_filename = dest_filename or os.path.basename(filename)
            attribs = {'n': dest_filename}

            encrypt_attribs = base64_url_encode(
                encrypt_attr(attribs, ul_key[:4]))
            key = [
                ul_key[0] ^ ul_key[4], ul_key[1] ^ ul_key[5],
                ul_key[2] ^ meta_mac[0], ul_key[3] ^ meta_mac[1], ul_key[4],
                ul_key[5], meta_mac[0], meta_mac[1]
            ]
            encrypted_key = a32_to_base64(encrypt_key(key, self.master_key))
            logger.info('Sending request to update attributes')
            # update attributes
            data = self._api_request({
                'a':
                'p',
                't':
                dest,
                'i':
                self.request_id,
                'n': [{
                    'h': completion_file_handle,
                    't': 0,
                    'a': encrypt_attribs,
                    'k': encrypted_key
                }]
            })
            logger.info('Upload complete')
            return data
```

The problem is I'm importing Mega class from mega.mega and while uploading file into Mega Cloud I can't see any logs printed out in my console.

Comment: What's wrong with your code ?

Comment: Also what do you mean by intercept? Can you just tail the log file?

Comment: Well, I am importing Mega class from mega.mega and while uploading file into cloud I can't see any logs printed out in my console. Also as I understand - tail log file will print me the last few lines of the logs, but I would like to see logs in real time - like seeing the progress of upload.